# rsync doesn't copy *only* modifications

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync` to backup my files. I choose `rysnc` because it (should) use modification times to determine if changes have been made and if files need to be updated.

I started my backup (from my computer system (debian) to a portable external hard drive) with this command:

```
rsync -avz --update --delete --stats --progress --exclude-from=/home/user/scripts/ExclusionRSync --backup --backup-dir=/media/user/hdd/backups/deleted-files /home/user/ /media/user/hdd/backups/backup_user
```

It worked well and took a lot of time. I believed the second time would be very quick (since I didn't modify files). Unfortunately, the 2nd, 3th, 4th, ... times took as long as the first one. I still see all my files being copied even if these files are already in my portable hard drive.

I don't understand why rsync doesn't copy only modifications (rsync is known to be efficient and only copy changes and I specificly call `--update` option).

A side effect of this problem is that all files are moved to my backup dir (deleted-filed) as soon as they are transfered. Indeed, rsync delete the previous file before to copy the same file during each update...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution reading [an answer on Serverfault.SE](https://serverfault.com/questions/54949/how-can-i-use-rsync-with-a-fat-file-system). The Fat filesystem was messing with timestamps:

> FAT doesn't track modification times on files as precisely as, say
>   ext3 (FAT is only precise to within a 2 second window). This leads to
>   particularly nasty behavior with rsync as it will sometimes decide
>   that the original files is newer or older than the backup file by
>   enough that it needs to re-copy the data or at least re-check the
>   hashes. All in all, it makes for very poor performance on backups. If
>   you must stick with FAT, look into rsync's --size-only and
>   --modify-window flags as workarounds.